# No file found for: /_ah/start on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jetty, http-status-code-403

I've recently changed from default scaling to manual scaling on my GAE local app.
I can get response from `/api/*` path but my welcome file doesn't work anymore.

I get

> Problem accessing /. Reason:
>
> Forbidden

and when starting server it says:

> com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
>
> WARNING: No file found for: /_ah/start

everything worked well before that here is my `appengine-web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <version>1.0</version>
    <manual-scaling>
        <instances>1</instances>
    </manual-scaling>
    <instance-class>B1</instance-class>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
        <static-files>
            <include path="/**.html"></include>
            </static-files>
    <resource-files>
        <include path="/**.json" />
    </resource-files>
</appengine-web-app>
```

and my `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <filter>
    <filter-name>connexionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>slFilters.connexionFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>restrictFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>slFilters.restrictFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>connexionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>restrictFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <cookie-config>
      <http-only>true</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
  </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

the `index.html` is a simple hello world html file and should be displayed when accessing `localhost:8080`

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/_ah/start` is getting hit because you chose manual scaling:

> **Manual Scaling:** Requests can run for up to 24 hours. A manually-scaled instance can choose to handle /_ah/start and execute a program or script for many hours without returning an HTTP response code. Task queue tasks can run up to 24 hours.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed

Whats url for your welcome file? how does that work

Comment: Thank you for your answer . I do have read that before but still dont understand Why I get a 403 error code. My base Url Is localhosr:8080 this Is where I get the problem. Any idea? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry I didn't upvote because that doesn't solve my problem but still you have no idea where that could come from ??

Comment: My experiences with app engine have been with python, which has a different set/style of config files unforutnately. So i can answer about general app engine behavior. Are you sure you didnt change more than just the scaling type? like if you change that one part of the config file back does it work? another thing that can cause 403s like this is in my config files i can define a set of routes as requiring 'admin' access, which mean you need to log into your google account that has access to your GCP project. Another thing is the order in which you define your routes matters.

Comment: maybe try implementing a handler for `/_ah/start`? maybe it needs to return a 200 for app engine to proceed normally

Comment: Ok thank you a lot for your answer. I will try the the 200 code straight ahead. when removing manual scaling everything back to normal and when creating a specific servlet (kind of a route class in JAVA) and forwarding to my index.html I get stuck in a StackOverflowError in an infinite loop

Comment: after creating a servlet for `/_ah/start` the `No file found` disappeared and I get in the log the port opened for my default instance. But still access to base route is forbidden

Comment: Can you share an screenshot with the full  error trace?

Comment: @HarifVelarde the problem is that there are no errors now that I've added a route to  `_ah/start` but still accessing to `index.html` gives 403 forbidden without trace